# Executing scripts without the Python 3.7 launcher and extenstion on Windows 10

Tags: python, variables, system, launcher

I would like to execute script as

> "foo"

instead of

> "py foo.py"

I have already had the proper setup but I had to reinstall the python and now it doesn't work.

In PATH I added the Python3 root folder and Scripts subfolder.

In PATHEXT I added ".PY" and ".PYW".

I also associated the file group with .py and redirected the executable by

```
assoc .py=Python.File
ftype Python.File=C:\Python3\pythonw.exe "%1" %*
```

If I type "py foo.py" I get desired output.

After typing "foo" or "foo.py" I won't get any output or error.

After typing "py foo" I get `(null): can't open file 'hello': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

It looks like the system variables are not effected by new settings, I have tried to restart pc, it din't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
   assoc .py=PythonScript 
   ftype PythonScript=py.exe %1 %*
   set PATHEXT=.py;%PATHEXT%
```

`py.exe` is the Python launcher and is located in `C:\windows\py.EXE` by default

Comment: I checked the location and the Python launcher is there but this setting unfortunately dosn't work for me.

Comment: OK it is finally working. I had to use the py.exe (insted of pythonw.exe) in C:\Python3 folder. Thanks